# Google Maps not working in Tizen 3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am working on a Tizen 3 M2 app that utilizes Google Maps API.

When I run it, I get a bunch of errors that seem to indicate that the Google Maps API is not loading.

The code works properly in regular web browsers, Tizen 1 and 2 but not in the emulator or on an actual device running Tizen 3 M2.

The sample Google Maps code that I am using can be found at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

Click on the tab that says 'JavaScript + HTML'.  I copy/pasted that code into an empty index.html file in a new project.

As mentioned, the code works perfectly pretty much everywhere except Tizen 3.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: It looks like Tizen 3  isn't currently supporting SSL very well.  In regards to Google Maps, it looks like they want people to use Web Sockets instead of AJAX.  I'm looking into that now.  Do any of you have any suggestions/comments in regards to Tizen 3 and Web Sockets that might help me out?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Tizen by Intel (as of the first part of January 2014) has an issue that forces the default output of Google Maps and Bing Maps to be forced to such a tiny size that you cant see it.  Use CSS to set the map size and all is good.  I wish that I had been able to figure this out sooner.